# How does routing work for product pages?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, product-page, routing

The Magento documentation says Magento URLs are built like `<store-url>/<store-code>/<front-name>/<controller-name>/<action-name>`, but I can't find anything about how routing is done when the URL isn't in that format.

When I have a catalog page that lists my products, each product has a destination URL like `http://example.com/my-product.html`.  How does the routing for that work, and how do I know what controller my request is being routed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te product urls are mapped to a module/controller/action url in the table `url_rewrite`.